# Python how to keep writing to a file without erasing what's already there

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-io, windows-7, python-3.3

Writing my python 3.3 program in Windows, I've run into a little problem. I'm trying to write some lines of instructions to a file for the program to execute. But every time I file.write() the next line, it replaces the previous line. I want to be able to keep writing as many lines to this file as possible. NOTE: Using "\n" doesn't seem to work because you don't know how many lines there are going to be. Please help! Here is my code (being a loop, I do run this multiple times):

```
menu = 0
while menu != None:
    menu = lipgui.choicebox("Select an option:", choices=["choice1", "choice2", "choice3"])
    file = open("file.txt", "w")
    if menu == "choice1":
       text_to_write = lipgui.enterbox("Text to write:")
       file.write(text_to_write)
```

Comment: also since it's python 3.3 you should be using with open('file.txt', 'w') as file rather than straight open

Comment: @user3012759 that feature was introduced in Python 2.5

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Every time you open a file for writing it is erased (truncated). Open the file for *appending* instead, or open the file *just once* and keep it open.

To open a file for appending, use `a` instead of `w` for the mode:

```
while menu != None:
    menu = lipgui.choicebox("Select an option:", choices=["choice1", "choice2", "choice3"])
    file = open("file.txt", "a")
    if menu == "choice1":
       text_to_write = lipgui.enterbox("Text to write:")
       file.write(text_to_write)
```

or open the file *outside the loop*:

```
file = open("file.txt", "w")

while menu != None:
    menu = lipgui.choicebox("Select an option:", choices=["choice1", "choice2", "choice3"])
    if menu == "choice1":
       text_to_write = lipgui.enterbox("Text to write:")
       file.write(text_to_write)
```

or just once the first time you need it:

```
file = None

while menu != None:
    menu = lipgui.choicebox("Select an option:", choices=["choice1", "choice2", "choice3"])
    if file is None:
        file = open("file.txt", "w")
    if menu == "choice1":
       text_to_write = lipgui.enterbox("Text to write:")
       file.write(text_to_write)
```

Comment: But i'm not re-opening the file. I'm just writing to it again!

Comment: @LukeDinkler: then show us your code; if lines are replaced, then you are doing something unusual.

Comment: @LukeDinkler: you **are** reopening the file. Each time you call `open()`.

Comment: Oh! Silly Mistake! Now how do I write each line on a new line?

Comment: @LukeDinkler: add a newline character to the text you write.

Comment: Like: file.write(text + "\n")?

Comment: @LukeDinkler: exactly.

Answer (score 0):

In order to solve this kind of problem and work on all applications including real time applications, you have to first open a file in append mode outside loop
and open the same file in write mode inside the loop.

Here is the example in different context(Removing duplicates in real time).

```
import sched, time
s = sched.scheduler(time.time, time.sleep)
outfile = open('D:/RemoveDup.txt', "a")
def do_something(sc):  #loop  
    outfile = open('D:/RemoveDup.txt', "w")
    #do your stuff........    
    infile = open('D:/test.txt', "r")
    lines_seen = set()
    for line in infile:
        if line not in lines_seen:
            outfile.write(line)
            lines_seen.add(line)
    s.enter(10, 1, do_something, (sc,))
    s.enter(10, 1, do_something, (s,))
s.run()
```